# How can I validate an email field in Google Forms against data in a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I want to validate the collect email field of google forms with the emails exists in my spreadsheet.
If the email does not exist it should show a message that you are not register please click on the url to register first.
I searched chat GPT also it gave me 100 of scripts but nothing works.

Comment: Hi. If you are thinking of some kind of real-time validation between the Google form and the sheet, then that is not possible. You can use Google sheets to upload the data validation to Forms, but in the case of email that might not be convenient. A possibility might be to use an HTML form - have you considered/researched that option.

Comment: HTML form is possible but I am using many other addons and google apps which completely depends on my this googleform only. Can validation be possible after form submit ?

Comment: `Can validation be possible after form submit ?` Within the Google Form = Yes, but limited. Google Forms: dynamic linking to Google Sheets = No.